# Altering "readtimeout" for Lambda Invoke in AirFlow

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, airflow, mwaa

I have a lambda that consistently takes longer than 1 minute to finish executing. This is a problem with the default `LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator`, since by default, it's hook creates a *Boto3* connection with a default *read_timeout* of 60s (meaning that after 60s, if the Lambda has not returned any result, the connection will abort with a Read Timeout error).

I solved the problem by creating a custom operator and hook where I was able to change the connection. But holy moly, surely there is a better way! I am an experienced Software Engineer but I hardly have experience with Python. So I fear I over engineered this and there is a better way.

Here is what I did:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any
from botocore.config import Config

from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils import trim_none_values
from cached_property import cached_property
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.base_aws import AwsBaseHook
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function import LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator as BaseLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator

class LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(BaseLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator):
    @cached_property
    def hook(self) -> LambdaHook:
        return LambdaHook(aws_conn_id=self.aws_conn_id)

class LambdaHook(AwsBaseHook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        kwargs["client_type"] = "lambda"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def conn(self):
        # All this effort to basically be able to pass this config in
        config_dict = {"connect_timeout": 5, "read_timeout": 900, "tcp_keepalive": True}
        config = Config(**config_dict)
        return self.get_client_type(self.region_name, config)

    def invoke_lambda(
        self,
        *,
        function_name: str,
        invocation_type: str | None = None,
        log_type: str | None = None,
        client_context: str | None = None,
        payload: str | None = None,
        qualifier: str | None = None,
    ):
        invoke_args = {
            "FunctionName": function_name,
            "InvocationType": invocation_type,
            "LogType": log_type,
            "ClientContext": client_context,
            "Payload": payload,
            "Qualifier": qualifier,
        }
        return self.conn.invoke(**trim_none_values(invoke_args))
```

The above code works (tested in Airflow 2.5.1) and my Dags do not suffer from a timeout. Is there a better way?

NOTE: For those that say I should just do this asynchronously, you have a point. However, that's a different question ;)

Comment: Looking at the code I don't think there's an easy way to do that. You could set `invocation_type="Event"` and it will invoke the lambda asynchronously, but then it's hard to tell if the lambda as finished or not.

Comment: I know about async, but as mentioned originally in the description, I did not want to go that route. You see, my lambda only takes about 1 minute and 15 seconds - so it makes sense to just increase the read_timeout time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be way easier to define the read_timeout in the aws connection?
Pass in:

```py
{"connect_timeout": 5, "read_timeout": 900, "tcp_keepalive": True}
```

to the extras in an aws connection and then use that connection when calling the LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I altered the connection to add what you described and it seemed to be ignored. I looked at the source and it seems it may be ignored. However, I also could have formatted the JSON incorrectly (although I triple checked it).

Comment: Try to extract and print the extras from your connection with a PythonOperator and see if it's ignored, try to create a new connection with the extra values. I have faced similar issues and the connection was not properly updated when adding the extra just in the UI. Creating a new connection worked for me

Comment: You are correct. Explicitly creating a new connection with the extra fields works just fine.

Comment: Following **extras** worked for me:
`{"config_kwargs": {"read_timeout": 900}}`