# Altering "readtimeout" for Lambda Invoke in AirFlow (Updated)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, airflow

I am new to Airflow and trying to create a framework to call lambda functions. My airflow is running on AWS Ubuntu server and I have a lambda that consistently takes longer than 1 minute to finish executing. This is a problem with the default LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator, since by default, it's hook creates a Boto3 connection with a default read_timeout of 60s (meaning that after 60s, if the Lambda has not returned any result, the connection will abort with a Read Timeout error).

I have found an article when there are 2 solutions:

1. Create custom operator and hook (Not sure how to implement this.)
2. Add extras in the aws connection in Airflow.

[Altering "readtimeout" for Lambda Invoke in AirFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117009/altering-readtimeout-for-lambda-invoke-in-airflow/76118381#76118381)

I tried the 2nd approach by adding extras in aws connection in airflow as answered in below link but still getting the timeout error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is how I have added extras in my aws connection in Airflow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxI1z.png)